# WPF datagrid oddity

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I've been implementing a way to 'tick all' checkboxes in my datagrid.

```
public void SelectAllCheckboxes(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (bindSource != null)
        {
            DataView list = (DataView)bindSource.List;
            System.Windows.Controls.Button btn = e.OriginalSource as System.Windows.Controls.Button;
            if (btn.Content.ToString() == "Select All")
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
                {
                    list[i]["Approve?"] = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
                {
                    list[i]["Approve?"] = false;
                }
            }
            bindSource.DataSource = list;
            dataGrid.DataContext = bindSource;
        }
    }
```

When I use the method once to tick all checkboxes, it works fine. All checkboxes are ticked. However, when I try to 'select none' to untick everything the first checkbox will never ever change. The tick stays there.

This also happens in the reverse order of selection.

The datarow does retain the intended true/false value, it's just not represented on the grid.

What on earth is going on?

[edit]After some further testing, the checkbox works properly after I "wake it up" by clicking on it a few times and changing its ticked value. Very very strange.